# ASP.NET document.getElementById('<%=Control.ClientID%>'); returns null

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to retrieve a server control in JavaScript. For testing purposes I am calling the JavaScript function from the page load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "js", "confirmCallBack();", true);
}
```

And my JavaScript function is

```
function confirmCallBack() {
    var a = document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("PlaceHolderContent").FindControl("Button1").ClientID %>');
    var b = document.getElementById('<%=Button1.ClientID%>');
}
```

my problem is that both a and b return null. Even when I view the page source the correct ClientID is returned.

I should add that I'm using master page.

Any ideas.

Comment: Im gonna try to accomplish what you want, but for a fast answer why dont you try to pass the Id via parameter in the Page Load? confirmCallBack(Button1.ClientID);

Comment: Easy answer is don't use auto generated ASP ids

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gotcha!

You have to use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`

Here My Example.

MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs"
    Inherits="prueba.MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function confirmCallBack() {
            var a = document.getElementById('<%= Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").FindControl("Button1").ClientID %>');

            alert(a.value);

        }

    </script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="prueba.WebForm1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</asp:Content>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace prueba
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "js", "confirmCallBack();", true);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I was stuck on that for ages.

Comment: Thanks man, like the user before me, I was stuck on this for hours. I was close to ripping my hair out :0.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Button1` visible? I mean, from the server side. Make sure Button1.Visible is true.

Controls that aren't `Visible` won't be rendered in HTML, so although they are assigned a `ClientID`, they don't actually exist on the client side.

Comment: Is there any way to get ID of invisible asp.net controls?

Comment: @DKR the ClientID property gives you the ID that _would_ be given to the control _if_ it is rendered on the page. Otherwise this information is almost useless on the client side.